# Find and Replace All File Names in Folder - PHPStorm / WebStorm

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

Let's say I have the following directory structure:

```
-Root
    -some_file.php
    -other_file.php
    -third_file.php
```

How do I replace every instance of `file` in the above file names?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PhpStorm does not cover this task. You can only rename single file one by one or use custom shell script.

Answer (score 3):

It is pretty straightforward in PHP

```
$dir = scandir (".");
foreach ($dir as $fileName)
{
  $newFile = str_replace("foo", "bar", $fileName);
  rename($fileName,$newFile);
}
```

A couple of bits of advice:

1) I worked this on a copy of the directory. All worked fine but the potential for an up cock is pretty significant.

2) you can also use `str_ireplace` for case insensitive replacing. (I spotted a naming snafu while doing this and that sped things up a little.)

3) if you have ANY `regex` chops this sould be v powerful. Sadly I've never mastered it.

PS I tried Total Commander spent a while trying to find how to replace names. This looked quicker.

Answer (score 2):

I just googled the same thing and ended up using Total Commander to multi-rename a few hundred files and then PHPStorm > Replace in Path to replace all the references. The entire process took 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I used Renamer which worked pretty well https://www.den4b.com/products/renamer

It didn't rename folders though, so that would be an improvement I would like to see.